# Servicem8 - How to Send all new job data to Gohighlevel

Tags: servicem8

I need to extract all new or changed job data from servicem8 and send it to Gohighlevel inbound webhook. i cant seem to see what ive done wrong in the code. can ou please help me fix what is needed

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');

/**
 * This modified function fetches job details from ServiceM8 when the job status changes
 * and sends this information to the GoHighLevel API.
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    if (event.eventName != 'webhook_subscription') {
        callback(null, {});
        return;
    }

    var strJobUUID = event.eventArgs.entry[0].uuid;
    var strAccessToken = event.auth.accessToken;

    // Fetch job details from ServiceM8
    request.get({
        url: 'https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Job/' + strJobUUID + '.json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + strAccessToken
        }
    }, function(err, httpResponse, jobDetails) {
        if (httpResponse.statusCode != 200) {
            callback(null, {error: "Unable to fetch job details, received HTTP " + httpResponse.statusCode});
            return;
        }

        // Send the job details to GoHighLevel
        const goHighLevelEndpoint = 'https://services.leadconnectorhq.com/hooks/w9vDTCsTOySiIRVkLMpP/webhook-trigger/6b85b2ee-5f1e-478f-a05f-5bc00d698b10';
        const goHighLevelApiKey = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2NhdGlvbl9pZCI6Inc5dkRUQ3NUT3lTaUlSVmtMTXBQIiwiY29tcGFueV9pZCI6IkdrcmRLMzM2c29vbDFlVDJBajJkIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNzA1NjQ2MTg4Mjk3LCJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyX2lkIn0.N5Wt0sK0j8QtRi2o8fw4zT2uo4LiUzZkzNg7SswZwfg';

        request.post({
            url: goHighLevelEndpoint,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${goHighLevelApiKey}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            json: JSON.parse(jobDetails)
        }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (httpResponse.statusCode != 200) {
                callback(null, {error: "Unable to send job details to GoHighLevel, received HTTP " + httpResponse.statusCode});
                return;
            }

            // Job details sent successfully to GoHighLevel
            callback(null, {result: "Sent job details to GoHighLevel for job " + strJobUUID});
        });
    });
};
```

Manifest
`{ "name": "Webhook Addon for GoHighLevel Integration", "version": "1.0", "iconURL": "https://www.servicem8.com/images/addon-sdk-sample-icon.png", "supportURL": "https://support.youraddon.com", "supportEmail": "support@youraddon.com", "oauth": { "scope": "manage_jobs read_jobs" }, "actions": [], "menuItems": [], "webhooks": [ { "object": "job", "fields": [ "uuid", "status", "company_uuid" ], "events": [ "create", "update" ] } ] }`